# ZSH+GREP+REGEX. Why this snippet act as rm -r /

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, root

This is a little anecdote from earlier on why not running root is vital.

I was sorting my home directory and deleted a few compressed files I had, I wrote
`ls . | grep -P 'zip|tar|7z' | xargs rm` and thought, hey I could also write this as `rm -r $(ls . |  grep -P '...')` I suppose.

The second part I didn't mean to use it since there was nothing to delete, it was morelike a mental exercise, I wrote it next to the last command with a 'divider' to visually compare them.

`ls . | grep -P 'zip|tar|7z' | xargs rm **//** rm -r $(ls . |  grep -P '...')`

Being `**//**` the "divider" and `...` the mental "substitute" for `'zip|tar..'`

I thought this wouldn't run but to my surprise, it acted as `rm -r /`and tried to delete everything, luckily permissions saved me and nothing was deleted.

But I'm curious why it'd work that way,
my guess is that `rm **//**` somehow translated to `rm /` but I'm not sure.

Comment: `rm` is probably not the best command to use when experimenting.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: If you ran `rm **//** rm -r` in your home directory, it should only be deleting files from your home directory (but it would indeed delete all of them)

Comment: @oguzismail `**//**` would not expand to `/`, unless you're in `zsh`.

Comment: I think it matters what shell you were using at the time. You have tagged this with bost [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh]. Can we assume you were using `zsh`?

Answer (score 0):

In the `zsh` shell, `**//**` would expand to all names under `/` as well to all names below the current directory (recursively).

From an empty directory on my system:

```
$ echo **//**
/altroot /bin /boot /bsd /bsd.booted /bsd.rd /bsd.sp /dev /etc /extra /home /mnt /root /sbin /sys /tmp /tmp_mnt /usr /var /vol
```

Why? Well, `**/` matches all directories recursively under the current directory.  More importantly, it matches the *current* directory, but since the current directory's name is not available inside the current directory, there's no entry returned for that.

*However*, when you add a `/` to that to create `**//`, then you get a lone `/` back for the current directory.  Again in an empty directory:

```
$ echo **//
/
```

Then, if you add a further `**` to make `**//**`, you pick up all names from the root directory, together with all names from the current directory and below (directory names from the current directory and below would occur twice in the list).

Your `xargs` is calling

```
rm **//** rm -r $(ls . |  grep -P '...')
```

If you're using GNU `rm`, it will helpfully rearrange the command line so that it is interpreted the same as

```
rm -r **//** rm $(ls . |  grep -P '...')
```

What this does should now be clear.

---

If you want to delete all regular files in the current directory that have filename suffixes `.zip`, `.tar` or `.7z`, use

```
rm ./*.(zip|tar|7z)(.)
```

in the `zsh` shell.  If want to do that recursively down into subdirectories, use

```
rm ./**/*.(zip|tar|7z)(.)
```

The glob qualifier `(.)` makes the globbing pattern only match regular files.  You could even restrict it to files above a certain size, say 10MB, with `./**/*.(zip|tar|7z)(.Lm+10)`.

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that the `ls ... | xargs ....` solution also works if there are really a lot of files involved, while your `rm $( .... )` might produce a *argument list too long* error. But if this is not an issue in your case, an even simpler attempt would be (assuming here Zsh; I don't understand why you tagged this *bash*, since you explicitly refer to Zsh only in your question)

```
rm *(zip|tar|7z)*(N)
```

which would express your original statement; I believe however that you really meant

```
rm -- *.(zip|tar|7z)(N)
```

because the solution you posted would also remove a file `tarpit.txt`, for instance. The `(N)` flag is a frail attempt to treat the case, that you don't have any file matching the pattern. Without the `(N)`, you would get an error message from Zsh, and `rm` would receive the unexpanded file pattern, and, since it is unlikely that a file of this name exists, would output a second error message. By using `(N)`, Zsh would simply pass nothing in this case (without complaining), and in fact `rm` would be invoked without arguments. Of course you would then get a *rm: missing operand* on stderr, and if you don't like this, you can filter this message.

**UPDATES**:

As Kusalananda has pointed out in his/her comment, omitting the `(N)` would, by default, make zsh only print an error message, if no files match the pattern, but not cause `rm` to be invoked.

Also added the `--` flag to `rm` to allow removal of, i.e., a file called `-rf.tar`.

Comment: `zsh`, by default, would not execute `rm` if you gave it a globbing pattern that did not expand to anything. With `(N)`, you guarantee that `rm` would be executed with an empty list if there are no matches. I don't know if this is wanted.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot.